# Only display price when value exist

Tags: posts

I got two price value,(WpForest_price) first price (WpForest_price 1) second price,what i want is if the user bought with the value of first price and it will show the price and for second price show the second price means on and off in single sumarry payment page.Right now the coding i made only show for just one price (WpForest_price) first price.How to code it using my statement below.

This is my code..

```
if(count($res) > 0){
echo '<table width="100%">';
echo '<thead><tr>';
echo '<th>'.__('Post Name','WpForest').'</th>';
echo '<th>'.__('Price','WpForest').'</th>';
echo '<th>'.__('Date Purchased','WpForest').'</th>';
echo '<th>'.__('Download','WpForest').'</th>';
echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
//-------------
foreach($res as $row){
  if (!empty($row->pid)) {
  $post_id = get_post($row->pid);
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th><a href="'.get_permalink($post_id->ID).'">'.$post_id->post_title .'</a></th>';
echo '<th>'.wpforest_currency_simb().get_post_meta( $post_id->ID, 'WpForest_price', true ).' '.  get_option('wpf_paypal_cur').'</th>';
echo '<th>'.date('d-M-Y',strtotime($row->complete_date)).'</th>';
echo '<th><a href="'.home_url().'/download/'.$post_id->ID.'">'.__('Download Now', 'WpForest').'</a></th>';
echo '</tr>';
}
 } echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: It looks like you tried to add your code to my answer and it was rejected. Add that code to your question by editing it. Indent each line of code with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this produces the first price currently:

```
echo '<th>' . wpforest_currency_simb() . get_post_meta( $post_id->ID, 'WpForest_price', true ) . ' ' . get_option( 'wpf_paypal_cur' ) . '</th>';z
```

And assuming I understand the question, this should test for the first price:

```
$price = get_post_meta( $post_id->ID, 'WpForest_price', true );
if ( $price )
    echo '<th>' . wpforest_currency_simb() . "$price " . get_option( 'wpf_paypal_cur' ) . '</th>';
```

And this should test for the second price:

```
$price = get_post_meta( $post_id->ID, 'WpForest_price 1', true );
if ( $price )
    echo '<th>' . wpforest_currency_simb() . "$price " . get_option( 'wpf_paypal_cur' ) . '</th>';
```

---

From the comments it appears you want this:

```
if ( some test )
    $price = get_post_meta( $post_id->ID, 'WpForest_price', true );
else
    $price = get_post_meta( $post_id->ID, 'WpForest_price 1', true );

echo '<th>' . wpforest_currency_simb() . "$price " . get_option( 'wpf_paypal_cur' ) . '</th>';
```

But I cannot tell what test you want to use.

Comment: Both of the price appear charles,just wanted only what they bought to be appear only between the two price.

Comment: can it be using if and else....

Comment: WpForest_price and WpForest_price 1 has a value,i think it should appear,what i mean is the only price they bought should appear.

Comment: let say WpForest_price value $10 if they bought this price the only should appear but for the WpForest_price 1 had a value but i don't want it to appear cause they only bought for the value of $10.

Comment: I don't understand. You cannot buy a price. A price is the value attached to something. For example, I can buy a dog at a certain price. But I am buying a dog, not a price. Using this example, how would we know (with PHP code) that the customer is buying a dog at WpForest_price? Or does WpForest_price hold something other than a price?

Comment: ok charles ,i bought this scripts from themehive and made a lot of modify,i seek help from them but not excatly answer i got,i am now almost completely building my site,check my site with the temporary domain at scriptszone.cu.cc and click any item and you can look at the price, so that you know what i'm talking about between the regular price and extended price,if they buy the regular price than it will show the regular price on download page not both price.The code you gave shows both price on download page.

Comment: So, what determines whether they get the regular price or the extended price? What do we test for?

Comment: The code above shows a static info for regular price,if my customers buy the extended price it will display regular price cause WpForest_price is for regular price,i try your code it show both of the price,what i want to make it can switch between the two price.This is what i really mean example in logical: if the user buy in extended price than show extended price(regular price will not be display) else if the user buy in regular price show the regular price(extended price will not be display)the user will only buy one of them but all the result will came out in one page.

Comment: But ... How do we determine whether the user bought at the regular price or at the extended price?

Comment: they can choose the price on the price box by clicking it,i had set up the rest starting from process payment until complete payment for the two price that mean the process will in two different way,only to display the price they bought,ok to give the full picture use this user name to login: username: ynh password: 105847 and click download tab and you can see the price,right now the price is the regular price but how to switch if the user buy the extended price in the price display by using the same page.

Comment: under logical of ( some test ), what do u think should replace that,give me some example,i got blur on this part or you want to look at the full statement.

Comment: I don't know. You have not offered enough information to figure out what that test should be. You have to tell us.

Comment: Hilarious comments here. @mus720714 *Please* use commas, upper and lower case characters, etc. Your sentences ignore every English language rule I've ever heard off. Please, please, please accept the fact that this is _no_ chat, but something that later readers will read as well.